# Can I slice literal type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

In TypeScript, when I want to edit literal type, it is working.

```js
type Old = "helloWorld"
//   ^? "helloWorld"
type New = `${Old}New`
//   ^? "helloWorldNew"
```

But how can I make this.

```js
type Old = "helloWorld"
//   ^? "helloWorld"
type New = Slice<"helloWorld",5> // < Is it possible
//   ^? "World"
```

Comment: @Jamiec that does not work. `Old` is nothing that exists on runtime.

Comment: @fjc quite right, I didnt read it properly I thought it was just a string

Comment: There is no helper like `Slice` but see if [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gNgEygXigIgBYTnA9gdVwCdE0BYAKAHoqo6A9AfnSxwONMtEigDkIA7iigADACQBveAgC+-ASMo06UJi2x5CJBPPIUu4aAAkNBADz4oEAB7AIAOwQBnKE+BEAlvYDmAPmGWNnaOLqKseJJeAGYQRFD4MiJQzIG2Ds5QAORaiJnJ8VAAXFD2EABusUWlFUQA3JQGPDlIqCZs+GaZ4ezamb4NFEA) helps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no Slice in ts, but maybe would a split match your needs ?

```
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] : [S];
```

Line 1 declares two params, we'll use single characters for brevity.
S represents the string to split, and D is the deliminator. This
line ensures they are both strings.

Line 2 checks if string is a literal, by checking if a general string
can be extended from the input string. If so, return a string array. We
can't work with non-literal string.

Line 3 checks if the string is empty, if so return an empty tuple

```
type S2 = Split<"", "."> // string[]

type S3 = Split<"1.2", "."> // ['1', '2']

type S4 = Split<"1.2.3", "."> // ['1', '2', '3']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028&ssl=57&ssc=39&pln=51&pc=1#code/PTAEBUFMFsAcBsCGAXSp4EtUCdHwM6gDGiAdqAEZoCu%20kAJqMgPaiQAeyuRyoZj0MhljUkqUPi4ZSAc3RZIueEwCesSPgB0AWABQICAAsNaSdmlzMOPKvX4ANKGlNq2Uo5LkqoWgz6FYbGZ1bGQMDUd%20YjJQeg0icyo9A1hmfHwMCng0LjJ8ADNmbEEw5lJCfKDoPgkpWSZWGOYKACtIHidyGIBBAAUASR1dZLAAYlHQAGU6uUmELDD68FZu8gB5VvbkPRGIGAQUNCtFPEJPHzpQWBQccv9QACJ8eeQAWlTpZHwHhs78xSYxl2%20GoFDMFkIzioyAA7pBIKRNKAAGJFNjsRBwbKaHE7fRgcCGDCEZBqNDEmrg%20rHJSgGFEoiGYhlQrFEmNKYwABqilemAA1qYZkNSeoIJMedgMmVQABeR4AFk0AEZNAAmB54gwAdTQ5wSkEONVFOVYHFyHWQxmZcDKCK%20oGY%20UBKFq5lkQx1kAA5PBlM8rHwEmkSTDWN7NN7iIZENwcFo9CbQABRThxyYwABuigAPBnoNnsNN3XJzQj6IQqTIAHxyvSgBucguKYsWdGoUgV0AAAwAJABvaT-bCgACyiBaRQAvpoB0OAaPpNPZ4PSMPQL0UIyp93QAB%20euN-ugQST7AALjHE6KjmgS4vY-vjmuyEZl83r6ZU9Al%20PiiCD4PAAwmQpDMLw1xSqYWYAlWPxTlqYAADLSGgyoSIYzCiIw3j5JiGCYLGTjOioWHetm6DMMwgqMK6VpoIE7QMG2HCYggGjnrsrFYpA56fEErwsIJ%20xiJAfIKEohBgNx7HnoIsDqPQglkvgrwwlghjCVihzidYBCIaAKGkGgapOIQiDMp2WAYGUNgmo44BkpMCTCLwmZ4Bg9CHCSMa8PRfwAi%20twnluxj4LsiAyIg0iSE2hatvUkGYpAOBDLsRloAAzGZgJoNgGiiLwTq5ZZ9DWbZ8COBgzpcNQOTGOQgTMJmnloE0mw8Ls6lWiVIJgjMASIOkfifKwZX5MO9pXGk5V3M47VtDwSL9DV1pVrs9DMBooBgbwJSMo49HkPlyCuOQ-lJt1TIxP%20aL4DG6hpboSbgJMcopmmiA8PmhY5q9krSqQ1YGYSFJhqQ3q8DGnbZE2kqgMqAAMiMAKSOFQJC%20E4vAUjdGI8Zxz1kqAABCiD0D9igk9QyBrAA0glcjyqmFrIJT2A5g8SqI5oqKuJoCqCwqDzA8M%20KgAAEswcKFo4LPpjBI7qX6oB4QRjrkFWhD0hgjKxGUkOq1gJWsiUSKg2cQ2QF1BHKGU8AqCFn50g1lIzKAMY%20Wgpuug8AAamgAJqaAAWg8jg63r-nGZw8jGfr227YTSbs8m2AAe98tfWziuc3zI4fKQvAh4orCF7wyIYNmIsGeMoAAErtK4GQUYzUwvIsMgg9ajEtVhhAybDyt26QDt0kU-IuwioCkdQHuIBRePZ26bYsE7B27KyJ5FGgpDUGQRB%20CQdCELPdJkLwYbYJPV0lY56jOeYsC8NzquGqd%20WXoPvHueY5O64Jag7EExiwMMsCQLw3Ylk6GvfKrxaCICyHqZgtpjJFwcBAIB2RzL5RqDIKijAYSIEdmvQUkBYC7AtJPYq-l8ogngF8JEEtFA%20nMhAwMJpCaJmJnMKweZ2zlkrDMRwAARARnYhEllrLKQ8DYqziK7G9PcK9ZAAG0AC6P5ZFTAUYQb0UZlEaK0boRsOiywSJ7HONcAJwBTgHCIuxq51wAFUdz7lAKo8AjgcSaF4VgHMzjRHVk0ZeVRkx1EAG4DIZQRrEdoSA6FMDDFcWMmIMFwl9MoLGGRZCw0ZKkngigKhogoPlFqpJPRgDevlRidB0G9XdmvAMWBIidlAGIik-k4iYDvKQFARRzZEnCuLTA8cEQgkSfRR2sY0AUHAkyLWT0DAxNMoydo-JITOnkbjeQel0aOzWUQfkbZqp4IRCcf0MxdjnG8OYuIjBKgoJKtIEQvAqzLS2cwRwJ0zpQLbLGXAKgkS6muWQQ2V8b4aR2mUXSFyVEyCWWAZMmgEWAgpMfXi3CxSTHQvKPxyAcxVkcA8TQNdQHIVQqAbKhyNnEQadAik%20xSRVU%20aAH5bg%20DkCZSQrB1sibYtMnil4nNw6PFJaLdKlKFTzzYRkO8CTozrN%20FhEcWdvqKw%20fSts%200wq7G7Ko3o%20V8gYHYPccA6jVEiMgD06Q-TsAWsmNQCaJr7jOPUbuI67Y4wlUYsa01AAKcAABKGBrB6KbwwFKCCqToApQBMVCyp12KHVdnA7A1ByD4o1r1J1frQD%20ucSGte4zXB8oMFaV00Ad4unIHadeTIbneywp2SpuwVpavqJtRO4FOhEHgNQOIJVukYF6XalN092VdBcOxR0zp0K7GyLIHqkcG1lGQNFO4-l5HXGGowea5kujYBkNQWNRd82TCDYiqYI6Z0YqxWgSY2UhV8IeKqDUxLxUGW1LbNlTcoIa0Pr8GQKU%20Aq38pGSsHcGD3qmNK59-jX3qk0JlUVJKyW7G-T1K0FJ%20RgRhNkegwHHBn3ulheAOE2pIN%20PlcmnLGAZriFGqIABHagCg%20Cb0gDCWdJUiAoOgBmrAjtv6EBoSJI0NJTiOC3t-QmIBdivFAKsdEtTCBBBpmgc0cYSmOxETELk-BFD8kxLsQwyBkCwHwOeEAsIFiKE0Hx6AwAvKkEzPQfkwBJAoFoMAZUmVEbKgAOyI2C2qAAbAAVhC8qAAnAADgVGF6VoARgKaU3E41pBZqqzRJtIgJ77SaFY4oFQGZsg8B04%20QUDcVBkFM%20Zyz1ngC2fM-ZxzwA7yCmwLVzskBMyefXadfAvn-MJcC2qNUgWYsBeRmqCLCpAuBdS%20LXokBgiwxjIvAgZp2AhBHfaPwt9WPscc-MEgqBGDbtjHQKUKXxa0FXuJ8Q8jJMEAjgya6uD8gZtAIpigNNoW8Hyo5099ycvYF2E1eg1AeA2XIHxuIFArYgPk%20LMzFmrMgBkBpUEDmUHABkJhUQmBFDAEQHCfAKCxKoG0qgWFShlJ2F2LsNYI4aOMH8qBZth9T28CyMwOQqRJBybAOjxrIA4iZn5zILQd5gyU-yMgPHTmTT4Bcs-MnpAwIZqIBYRn8Qn5vAVK8ZUrxoSIGAKMGnBw6evf1-gIAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
type Split<S extends string> = S extends ''
  ? []
  : S extends `${infer C}${infer R}`
  ? [C, ...Split<R>]
  : never

type TakeFirstNElements<
  T extends any[],
  N extends number,
  Result extends any[] = []
> = Result['length'] extends N
  ? Result
  : T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? TakeFirstNElements<Rest, N, [...Result, First]>
  : Result

type Join<T extends string[]> = T extends []
  ? ''
  : T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Head extends string
    ? `${Head}${Join<Tail extends string[] ? Tail : []>}`
    : never
  : never

type CutFirstChars<
  S extends string,
  N extends number,
  SArray = TakeFirstNElements<Split<S>, N>
> = Join<SArray extends string[] ? SArray : never>

type Result = CutFirstChars<'ami janina', 4>
// type Result = "ami "
```